# django admin specify database (not default)

Tags: django, django-models

I am using django admin to facilitate editing a database. Recently, we have added another database so using the default in DATABASES in the settings file would not make sense any more.

I now have this in my settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'animal_tracking': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'AnimalTracking',
        'USER': 'foo',
        'PASSWORD': 'bar',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'animal_information': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'AnimalInformation',
        'USER': 'foo',
        'PASSWORD': 'bar',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

My admin.py file contains:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from animal_tracking.models import at_animal_types, at_animals
# Register your models here.

class AnimalTypesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Sets how the fields are displayed in the add / change section.
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['type', ]}),
    ]
    # Sets what fields to be displayed in the change (view) section.
    list_display = ('type', )
# Registers the current model administration to the admin page.
admin.site.register(at_animal_types, AnimalTypesAdmin)

class AnimalsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Sets how the fields are displayed in the add / change section.
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['tracker_id', 'type', ]}),
        ('Log information (should not change)', {'fields': ['last_log', 'last_bat', 'last_lat', 'last_lon', ], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    # Sets what fields to be displayed in the change (view) section.
    list_display = ('tracker_id', 'type', 'last_log', 'last_bat', 'last_lat', 'last_lon', )
    # Sets what fields to allow filtering by.
    list_filter = ['type', ]
    # Sets what fields to allow searching by. Use table__field if foreign key.
    search_fields = ['tracker_id', 'type__type', ]
# Registers the current model administration to the admin page.
admin.site.register(at_animals, AnimalsAdmin)
```

Initially, the admin section would connect with the default database. But now that I removed the default and added the other 2 databases, I'm getting the following error:

[image: Django error.]

If I copy the settings of animal_tracking to default, it works. My question therefore is:

**How can I specify which database django admin should use?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd **better specify the default database**, if you leave default empty, you should write db [routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers).

in your admin, you can use any db you like:

```
class AnimalTypesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    using = 'animal_tracking'
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Tell Django to look for objects on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).using(self.using)
```

`save_model`,`delete_model`,`formfield_for_foreignkey`,`formfield_for_manytomany` should also be overridden like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface) in the example.